# Why does the scroll only take up half the width of the item? Locomotive scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, locomotive-scroll, locomotivejs

Why do the elements only scroll halfway through and then freeze? In the locomotive scrolling demonstration itself, these elements don't stop, but scroll further. I need the exact same thing. What needs to be set or changed for this?

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-davinci-p31ech?file=/src/banner.module.scss)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with the property `data-scroll-sticky`. I have removed it and tried, it was working.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/trusting-brown-rhzzfz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)